# Use Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova to create an xcarchive instead of ipa?

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, xcarchive

We're using [Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-vs.aspx) to build our app for iOS (and Windows).

We have a Mac running the remote agent. This works well, except we've only been able to have the setup produce signed .ipa files.

We're now looking into being able to create an unsigned "app" that we can deliver to our customer. They will then sign it with their enterprise certificate and distribute it within their orgainization (not the App Store).

The recommended way to deliver the app to the customer seems to be to create an xcarchive (I have looked at the option to deliver an ipa signed with our develoepr cert and then have the customer resign it with [iReSign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign), but that seems flaky).

Is there a way to do that with this setup without any manual steps on the Mac?

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way of producing xcarchive through remote-build.

Comment: But the generated project through cordova can be opened in XCode, And xcarchive can be generated by XCode on Mac.

Comment: @Strille Though i dont have much expertise on iOS platform, as far as i have analyzed, the easiest way to create an xcarchive is to use cocoon cloud service. Infact, it does gives the flexibility of generating both xcarchive and IPA. Suggest you to check this link - https://github.com/CocoonIO/cocoon-cloud-doc/blob/master/docs/user-guide/project-creation.md Let me know if it helps

Comment: @Strille Did you had a chance to look at this Strille?

Comment: @Gandhi, I'm afraid we can'y rely on a cloud service, we need to have full control of the build process and can't  rely on a 3rd party. But thanks for pointing it out, might be useful for another project.

Comment: @Strille Thanks for the response. Thought it may be useful as you were looking for a solution to generate xcarchive. But i believe you still have full control of your build process as it provides various config controls and it is already used by some renowned companies.

Comment: @Strille did you manage to crack this? What is your final approach on this? I m curious about this and the bounty too is about to end :(

Comment: Sorry, I have been busy with other tasks, so I haven't had time to think about this recently...

Comment: @Strille Wish i got the second upvote for my answer yesterday :( Missed at least 75 bounty points... How close :(

Answer (score 2):

As far as i have analyzed, the easiest way to create an xcarchive is to use cocoon cloud service. Infact, it does gives the flexibility of generating both xcarchive and IPA.

Also you have full control of your build process as it provides various config controls and it is already used by some renowned companies.Suggest to have a look at [cocoon platform](https://cocoon.io/) once.

I know you have mentioned that you cannot rely on 3rd party service but it is the easiest approach as far as i my analysis. Also it may be useful for someone who is struck with a similar issue to give it a shot.